# Program exits on "new MimeMessage(session)" in executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-mail, executable-jar, mime-message

I'm using javax.mail-1.6.1.jar to send emails from my gmail account.
 
It works fine when I'm running my program on eclipse, but when I run my program as an executable jar, it halts on this row - MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
No exception is thrown.

```
public void sendEmail(String from, String to,String subject, String body, 
String attachmentName){
  try {
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(fMailServerConfig, new SMTPAuthenticator());
      Log.getInstance(Emailer.class).getLogger().error("getProperty == "+fMailServerConfig.getProperty("mail.smtp.host"));

      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
      message.setSubject(subject);
      message.setSentDate(new Date());

      // Set the email msg text.
      MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
      messagePart.setText(body);

      // Set the email attachment file
      FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(attachmentName);
      MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
      attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
      attachmentPart.setFileName(fileDataSource.getName());

      // Create Multipart E-Mail.
      Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
      multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
      multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);

      message.setContent(multipart);
      // Send the msg. Don't forget to set the username and password
      // to authenticate to the mail server.
      Transport.send(message);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.getInstance(Emailer.class).getLogger().error("Cannot send email."+ e);
      System.err.println("Cannot send email. " + e);
  }
```

}

Comment: Is there a file with a name starting with something like `hs_errpid_`? The JVM creates such a file, if the entire VM died.

Comment: Does "halts" mean the program exits, or does it mean the program hangs?  How do you know it halts at that line?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Comment: @Jannik no, I did not find this file

Comment: @Bill Shannon yes, exits. 
JavaMail debug doesn't show nothing

Comment: It doesn't show "*Cannot send mail*" in your console? Nothing at all appears in your console?

Comment: If the JavaMail debug output shows literally nothing, then you're not even getting to the method above.  If the debug output actually shows something, edit your post to include the output.  Also, try catching Throwable instead of Exception to see if the JVM is failing.  And again, how do you know which lines causes it to exist?  Have you added print statements around the line that fails?

Comment: @sarshalom Well, then the problem is probably not caused by the JVM dying entirely. Have you tried to use a debugger? That's probably the easiest way to find the location where it exits.

Comment: @Vince Emigh no...just exit

Comment: @Bill Shannon Ok, I catched a Throwable and logged it, so I got this:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler

Yes, I found the failing line with print statements

Comment: @Jannik I can't debug it because it runs fine in the eclipse, the trouble is the executable jar

Comment: Fixed! 
I've added javax.activation.jar to the project.
Thanks everybody for you help., I couldn't do it with you.